# How to get percentage of occurrences of a column, grouped by another column? Python

Tags: python, pandas, percentage

I am trying to calculate the percentage of occurrences of a product (with hundreds of different products) according to the related Country. And I would like this % to be shown on another column

I managed to do it in a graph, but it is not visually pleasing.

I tried the following code:

```
df = data1.groupby('Country')
df['percent'] = (df['Products'] /
                df['Products'].value_counts())*100
df
```

I get the following error message :
"ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (111,2) (4209,)"

I also tried something like the following by modifying it to fit my dataframe, but without success.

```
gb = df.groupby("country")
gb['result'].agg(lambda x: len(x[x=="Fail"]) / len(x)).sort_values(by="% fail", ascending=False)
```

To summarize I would like something that would look like this:

```
   Countries    Products     Percentage
0  Country 1     Product 1     0.5
1  Country 1     Product 2     0.01
2  Country 2     Product 1     0.2
3  Country 2     Product 2     0.05
```

And so on.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
df['percent'] = df.groupby('Country')['Products'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
```

Comment: I believe you messed up the parentheses somewhere in the code

Comment: That doesn't work: AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'groupby'

Comment: Please see the code again, it's `df.groupby()` not `gb.groupby`.